# how do I check for sql injection in cookie

Tags: cookies, sql

I am using sqlmap to test my website for vulnerabilities. However rather than testing for vulnerable variables in URL, I would like to test if cookie values are subject to sql injection. Is there a way to do it via sqlmap? And if not is there a tool for that?

Comment: To people voting to close as off-topic: He's talking about a tool he's running on his PC against his website(s) -- I'm not sure why you'd think this is off-topic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look on this article - link bellow. Perhaps you will find the solution from there.

[Are there any tools for scanning for SQL injection vulnerabilities while logged in?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/39833/are-there-any-tools-for-scanning-for-sql-injection-vulnerabilities-while-logged)

This [Security.StackExchange.com](https://security.stackexchange.com/) post says that there is an option for testing SQL injection on cookies

```
--cookie=COOKIE            {HTTP Cookie header}
```

You just need to paste in your Cookie where it says `HTTP Cookie header`

also there is a [list of all the options for sqlmap](https://github.com/sqlmapproject/sqlmap/wiki/Usage)

Comment: Thank you for your help. With some information from your link and followup googling I managed to get exactly what I wanted from sqlmap. Command I ended up using was:  python sqlmap.py --cookie="some_id=6" -u "http://localhost/" -p "some_id" --level 3 --dbms=MYSQL

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the `--level` value too two or above for sqlmap to test cookie injection. Example:

```
./sqlmap.py --cookie="user_id=1" -u "http://localhost/index.php" -p "user_id" --level 3
```

> By default sqlmap tests all GET parameters and POST parameters. When
>   the value of --level is >= 2 it tests also HTTP Cookie header values.
>   When this value is >= 3 it tests also HTTP User-Agent and HTTP Referer
>   header value for SQL injections. It is however possible to manually
>   specify a comma-separated list of parameter(s) that you want sqlmap to
>   test. This will bypass the dependence on value of --level too.

https://github.com/sqlmapproject/sqlmap/wiki/Usage